# Is it okay to use Apple logo as a part of an icon in a website?

Tags: logo, icon, copyright, apple

I'm working on a website for a data recovery company.

I need to make an icon of a MacBook, because they offer specialized service for OS X devices. I'm not sure if it is okay for me to place the Apple logo in the center of the "Screen" on the icon. It won't be a part of the company logo or used as a differentiating aesthetic factor of the website, but it will be placed in a couple places on a website to show visitors that this company offers specialized data recovery service for OS X devices.

Would this potentially get me into a legal trouble? Does anyone have a clear answer for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a link to their legal policies;
http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html

Looks like the **2. Compatibility** section could apply to your question.

Here's the information;
2. Compatibility: Developers may use Apple, Macintosh, iMac, or any other Apple word mark (but not the Apple Logo or other Apple-owned graphic symbol/logo) in a referential phrase on packaging or promotional/advertising materials to describe that the third party product is compatible with the referenced Apple product or technology, provided they comply with the following requirements.

a. The Apple word mark is not part of the product name.

b. The Apple word mark is used in a referential phrase such as “runs on,” “for use with,” “for,” or “compatible with.”

c. The Apple word mark appears less prominent than the product name.

d. The product is in fact compatible with, or otherwise works with, the referenced Apple product.

e. The reference to Apple does not create a sense of endorsement, sponsorship, or false association with Apple or Apple products or services.

f. The use does not show Apple or its products in a false or derogatory light.

Comment: Thanks. That's just the information I needed. Perhaps I will need to find another way around :/

Comment: Hey Doc, thanks for contributing. Could you please include the relevant part of the information from the linked page as a quote in the answer itself? That way your answer will be valuable if the page goes down or changes and saves people time

Comment: Sure, Zach, good idea.